No custom broadcasts are received on an android service
I'm developing some apps for a specific device running Android 11 (API level 30) in kotlin. I have 2 apps that need to communicate with each other and I have thought to do it using custom broadcasts. One of the apps is a service (S) and the other is a GUI app (G). Typically S will send a broadcast and G will receive it to execute some code and respond with another broadcast. I'm able to send broadcasts from S and receive them on G, but I'm not able to send from G and receive them on S. As you can see below I use the same mechanisms in both applications. Do the services have restrictions when receiving broadcasts?
Packages:

S: com.company.product.service
G: com.company.product.app

Some code from S (abbreviated for simplicity):
ComConstants:
package com.company.product.service.com

class MediaConstants
{
    companion object
    {
        const val MY_ACTION = "com.company.product.MY_ACTION"
        const val MY_ACTION_RESPONSE = "com.company.product.MY_ACTION_RESPONSE"
    }
}

MainActivity:
package com.company.product.service

// imports

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        val i = Intent(this, MainService::class.java)
        startForegroundService(i)
        finish()
    }
}

MainService:
package com.company.product.service

// imports

class MainService : Service()
{
    ...
    private var myActionResponseReceiver = MyActionResponseReceiver(this)
    
    override fun onCreate()
    {
        super.onCreate()
        registerReceivers()
    }
    override fun onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceivers()
    }
    
    private fun registerReceivers()
    {
        registerReceiver(myActionResponseReceiver, IntentFilter(MY_ACTION_RESPONSE))
    }
    private fun unregisterReceivers()
    {
        unregisterReceiver(myActionResponseReceiver)
    }

    override fun onStartCommand(intent: Intent?, flags: Int, startId: Int): Int
    {
        // Some code to receive TCP connections...
        sendBroadcast()
        // More code
    }

    fun sendBroadcast()
    {
        val intent = Intent(MY_ACTION)
        intent.putExtra(/* name and value */)
        sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
}

MyActionResponseReceiver:
package com.company.product.service.receivers

// imports

class MyActionResponseReceiver(): BroadcastReceiver()
{
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?)
    {
        Log.i("MyTag", "Broadcast received: ${intent?.action}")
    }
}

Some code from G (abbreviated for simplicity):
ComConstants:
package com.company.product.app.com

class MediaConstants
{
    companion object
    {
        const val MY_ACTION = "com.company.product.MY_ACTION"
        const val MY_ACTION_RESPONSE = "com.company.product.MY_ACTION_RESPONSE"
    }
}

MainActivity:
package com.company.product.app

// imports

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
{
    private var myActionReceiver = MyActionReceiver()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        // some view code

        registerReceivers()
    }    
    override fun onDestroy()
    {
        super.onDestroy()
        unregisterReceivers()
    }
    
    private fun registerReceivers()
    {
        registerReceiver(myActionReceiver, IntentFilter(MY_ACTION))
    }
    private fun unregisterReceivers()
    {
        unregisterReceiver(myActionReceiver)
    }
}

MyActionReceiver:
package com.company.product.app.receivers

class MyActionReceiver(): BroadcastReceiver()
{
    override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?)
    {
        Log.i("MyTag", "Broadcast received: ${intent?.action}")
        // some code
        sendResponseBroadcast()
    }

    fun sendResponseBroadcast()
    {
        val intent = Intent(MY_ACTION_RESPONSE)
        intent.setComponent(ComponentName("com.company.product.app", "com.company.product.service/.receivers.MyActionResponseReceiver"))
        intent.putExtra(/* name and value */)
        sendBroadcast(intent)
    }
}


Your two broadcasts do not closely resemble one another. G -> A uses an explicit broadcast for a manifest-registered receiver. A -> G uses an implicit broadcast. Have you tried using an explicit broadcast for a manifest-registered receiver for the A -> G path?

I don't undertand. Why do you say manifest-registered receiver? I don't have any receiver registered in the manifest.

intent.setComponent(ComponentName("com.company.product.app", "com.company.product.service/.receivers.MyActionResponseReceiver")) -- AFAIK, this requires MyActionResponseReceiver to be registered in the manifest of the receiving app. Regardless, you lack a setComponent() call on the A -> G broadcast.

After making different changes and tests I have come to these conclusions: setComponent() is not necessary in either of the 2 cases; in the GUI app, it is NOT necessary to register the receivers in the manifest; in the Service app, it is necessary to register the receivers in the manifest.

You are sure that the Activity is actually sending the broadcast Intent? You are sure that the Service is running at the same time? And you don't see onReceive() getting called in the Service?

The code you've pasted is inconsistent. In the Service you declare private var myActionResponseReceiver = MyActionResponseReceiver(this) but the code for MyActionResponseReceiver doesn't have a constructor that takes any parameters. Please edit your question and update the code so that it matches what you really have.

OK, thisremoved. This doesn't change anything about my previous comment. Thanks for your help, it made me do some tests that I wouldn't have done otherwise.
